# useContext returns an empty array

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a functional component and trying to pass its state as context. `useEffect` hook fills the state with data and I create a custom hook to give me back the result. When I try to use it in another component I always get an empty array. Please help

Context component :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext} from 'react'
import DB from './Database'

export const Database = createContext()

export const useFeaturedHotels = () => {
  return useContext(Database)
}

export const DatabaseProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    featuredHotels: [],
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const featuredHotels = DB.hotels.filter((hotel) => hotel.featured === true)
    setState(featuredHotels)
  }, [])

  return <Database.Provider value={state}>{children}</Database.Provider>
}
```

Child :

```
import React from 'react'
import {useFeaturedHotels} from './DatabaseContext'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core'

const HomeHotels = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const featuredHotels = useFeaturedHotels() // ----> always empty array
  console.log(featuredHotels)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to be calling `setState({...state, featuredHotels })`

Answer (score 0):

I did recommend using like this,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext} from 'react'
import DB from './Database'

export const Database = createContext()

export const DatabaseProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    featuredHotels: [],
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const featuredHotels = DB.hotels.filter((hotel) => hotel.featured === true)
    setState(featuredHotels)
  }, [])

  return <Database.Provider value={state}>{children}</Database.Provider>
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import {Database} from './DatabaseContext'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core'

const HomeHotels = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const featuredHotels = useContext(Database)
  console.log(featuredHotels)
}
```

this, should work.
I have never used ur pattern. i am taking a look at it now why its not working

Comment: Ye, I tried that already and have the same result - empty array

Comment: @cheffo0o whats the output of `featuredHotels` from the db, is it ok ?

Comment: Throughout the components tree, the data is present. I can console log it and I get first an empty array, but after that, I get what I need. The thing is, whenever I try to map over it , React throws a type error - map is not a function.I think somehow the data is being passed before use effect updates the state.Can that be the problem ?

Comment: @cheffo0o yep, useEffect is a side effect. ur components get redered first, and then the useEffect's run, So, u will always get that initial `[]`

Comment: Jesus christ,just find out the problem...Havent been sleeping for like 15 hours over  this and I'm kinda embarrassed to say it , but I'm not properly updating the state...instead of  initial state being  featuredHotels:[],i just made it useState([]) and everything worked ....

Comment: im really grateful for your help though,best of luck !

Comment: ur welcome :) take a break. and dont forget to upvote if it helped a bit